# Iteritems on a slice of a Python list

Tags: python, array, iterator

`iteritems` on a `dict` can useful.

Occasionally `iteritems` is useful for a slice of a list and this effect can be (crudely) implemented as follows:

```
class List(list):
  def iteritems(self, slice=None):
    if slice is None: return enumerate(self)
    else: return itertools.izip(range(*slice.indices(len(self))), self[slice])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  l=List("hAnGtEn")
  print l
  print list(l.iteritems())
  print list(l.iteritems(slice(1,None,2)))
```

Output:

```
['h', 'A', 'n', 'G', 't', 'E', 'n']
[(0, 'h'), (1, 'A'), (2, 'n'), (3, 'G'), (4, 't'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'n')]
[(1, 'A'), (3, 'G'), (5, 'E')]
```

Is there a more "pythonic" list slicing syntax that should be used?

This:

```
range(slice.start,slice.stop,slice.step)
```

does not handle certain special cases very well: e.g. where `stop=-1`, `start=None` or `step=None`. How can the example range/slice implementation be also improved?

edit:

```
range(slice.start,slice.stop,slice.step)
```

is better handled with:

```
range(*slice.indices(len(self)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
class IterItems(object):
  def __init__(self, master_l):
    self.master_l=master_l
    return super(IterItems,self).__init__()

  def __call__(self, *sss_l):
    if not sss_l: return enumerate(self.master_l)
    else: return self[slice(*sss_l)]

  def __getitem__(self,sss):
    if not isinstance(sss, slice):
      yield sss,self.master_l[sss]
    else:
      sss_l=sss.indices(len(self.master_l))
      for key in range(*sss_l): yield key,self.master_l[key]

class ListItems(list):
  def __init__(self, *arg_l, **arg_d):
    self.iteritems=IterItems(self)
    return super(ListItems,self).__init__(*arg_l, **arg_d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  l=ListItems("hAnGtEn")
  print list(l.iteritems())
  print list(l.iteritems[1::2])
  for item in l.iteritems[1::2]: print item,
  print
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'h'), (1, 'A'), (2, 'n'), (3, 'G'), (4, 't'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'n')]
[(1, 'A'), (3, 'G'), (5, 'E')]
(1, 'A') (3, 'G') (5, 'E')
```

This new class `ListItems` works for an arbitrarily large list, providing a useful iterator that avoids loading the entire "list" into memory.

Or (if given it is feasible to short sub-slice the original long list) try...

```
>>> l="hAnGtEn"
>>> sss=slice(1,None,2)
>>> zip(l[sss],xrange(*sss.indices(len(l))))
[('A', 1), ('G', 3), ('E', 5)]
```

Or (using strict iteration):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l="hAnGtEn"
>>> sss=slice(1,None,2)
>>> sss=sss.indices(len(l))
>>> list(itertools.izip(itertools.islice(l,*sss),xrange(*sss)))
[('A', 1), ('G', 3), ('E', 5)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
range(slice.start,slice.stop,slice.step)
```

you could use this expression that handles the special cases too

```
range(len(self))[slice]
```

(This works with `range` on both Python 2 and 3, but not with Python 2 `xrange` even though it is mostly equivalent to Python 3 `range`)

Comment: I just figured out the "indicies" does a better job of range slicing: e.g. `range(*slice.indices(len(self))`

Comment: @NevilleDNZ Good find! That works even with `xrange`

Answer (score -1):

The more pythonic way is to use `enumerate()`:

```
>>> l = 'hAnGtEn'
>>> l
'hAnGtEn'
>>> list(enumerate(l))
[(0, 'h'), (1, 'A'), (2, 'n'), (3, 'G'), (4, 't'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'n')]
>>> list(enumerate(l))[1::2]
[(1, 'A'), (3, 'G'), (5, 'E')]
>>>
```

Comment: The original already uses `enumerate`.

Comment: You are right. I didn't study it fully. I was making the point that enumerate alone is sufficient rather than defining a new class.

Comment: The output is perfect, but I was hoping to avoid enumerating the entire (million item) list.  (Hence the use of a selective iteritems)